# Crock Pot Knob Turner

Tags: control, sensors, stepper-motor

I have a Crock Pot with an analog knob and would like to find a way to turn the knob by using and appliance timer. I have no idea where to begin. I need help.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? What is your end goal, to turn the crock pot on and off? Also, can you provide a link/picture/part number of your analog crock pot?

Comment: Why are you using an appliance timer? Are you trying to make it so you turn the timer (which turns the knob) to a given time setting and then it slowly turns back to 0 and turns off the crock pot? I am tempted to answer the only way we can: "glue the appliance timer to the knob, then rotate".

Comment: I want to use digital appliance timer to switch it to warm after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Someone designed an automated combination lock picker, perhaps this could inspire.

Answer (score 2):

You might be better served by using a PID "profile controller" -- it would be easier (cheaper) and more accurate than trying to manually control the knob.  These are also called "Ramp/Soak controllers".  They allow you to set different temperatures for different times.  A solid-state relay model (SSR) would probably be the most appropriate for what you are doing.

You would keep your crock pot set on high, put the temperature sensor inside, and let the PID controller do the rest.  It works by cycling the power on and off, trying to maintain the proper temperature during each of the time periods you programmed.

Answer (score 1):

If your analog knob just turns a potentiometer, then you can replace that device with a digital potentiometer (for example, this:  http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=MCP4161).  You need to make sure the Ohm range of your analog potentiometer is covered by the capabilities of the digital potentiometer.  They are typically controlled via commands from a microcontroller.  You can also see if you can find a voltage-controlled resistor (varistor) that covers the range you need.  I've never tried to do that with a varistor, though.

If your analog knob is like the one on my crock pot, then it really isn't analog.  It's a four-position switch.  You can use any little control card with digital outputs to replace that.  Be careful, though, you might need to throw relays in between your digital output and the signal lines, depending on the characteristics of the device that receives the output of the knob.

Comment: you can't if the potentiometer is operating at mains voltage like light dimmers do.

Comment: in any case the knob probably operates a screw or cam that adjusts a bimetallic thermostat.